# Cannot $uibModal inside directive but accessible in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal

I want to make directive to open a modal. But $uibModal is not defined inside directive .

```
var app=angular.module("app",['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
    console.log("$uibModal controller",$uibModal);//getting object
});

app.directive('showPopUp',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs,$uibModal) {
            console.log("$uibModal",$uibModal);//undefined here
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                  templateUrl: 'popup.html',
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                  scope.selected = selectedItem;
                }, function () {
                });

        }  
    }
});
```

How can I use $uibModal inside my directive to open modal ?

Comment: I think you can add controller to your directive and inject $uibModal there. It will work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directive link function is not injectable, it takes fixed set of parameters in fixed order. But you can inject services into directive function itself:

```
app.directive('showPopUp', function($uibModal) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'popup.html',
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
                scope.selected = selectedItem;
            }, function() {});

        }
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jwNOM94DtyRIXTdhvJmy?p=preview

Comment: After injecting services into directive function itself the code runs continuously and browser hangs.

Comment: This is not possible with the code I posted. It means that you messed up something in you app. I posted a demo in answer.